# Try to upgrade application into iris-6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6, ruby-on-rails-6.1

Using rails version - Rails 6.1.3.2

ruby version - ruby 2.7.3

```plaintext
You're using a cache store that doesn't support native cache versioning.
 
Your best option is to upgrade to a newer version of ActiveSupport::Cache::RedisStore that supports cache versioning 
(ActiveSupport::Cache::RedisStore.supports_cache_versioning?

#2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.3.2/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:106:in block (3 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/home/application/project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in class_eval'
/home/application/project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in block in execute_hook'
/home/application/project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:61:in with_execution_control'
/home/application/project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:66:in execute_hook'
/home/application/project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in block in on_load'
/home/application/project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in each'
/home/application/project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in on_load'
/home/application/project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.3.2/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:103:in block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/home/application/project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:68:in block in execute_hook'
/home/application/project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:61:in with_execution_control'
/home/application/project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:66:in execute_hook'
/home/application/project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:52:in block in run_load_hooks'
/home/application/project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in each'
/home/application/project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in run_load_hooks'
/home/application/project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:140:in block in module:Finisher'
/home/application/project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in instance_exec'
/home/application/project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in run'
/home/application/project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in block in run_initializers'
/home/application/project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in run_initializers'
/home/application/project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/application.rb:384:in initialize!'
/home/application/project/releases/20211004174101/config/environment.rb:5:in <top (required)>'
/home/application/project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.2/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in require'
/home/application/project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.2/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in require'
/home/application/project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in block in require'
/home/application/project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in load_dependency'
/home/application/project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in require'
/home/application/project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/application.rb:360:in require_environment!'
/home/application/project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/application.rb:526:in block in run_tasks_blocks'
/home/application/project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/airbrake-11.0.3/lib/airbrake/rake.rb:17:in execute'
/home/application/project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.2/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:61:in block (2 levels) in define'
/home/application/project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/airbrake-11.0.3/lib/airbrake/rake.rb:17:in execute'
/home/application/project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/exe/rake:27:in <top (required)>'
/home/application/project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in eval'
/home/application/project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `'
Tasks: TOP => environment
```

Please let be know how to solve this error.

Answer (score 0):

The Redis cache store implementation shipped with Rails (since version 5.2) should support fully the required feature.

However, it appears that you are using a different Redis cache implementation (such as the [redis-activesupport](https://github.com/redis-store/redis-activesupport) gem). With Rails 6.1, you should remove this gem and use the built-in `ActiveSupport::Cache::RedisCacheStore` instead.

Comment: Hello,I have install gem 'redis-activesupport' and added this line into application.rb file but still throws same error - ActiveSupport::Cache.lookup_store :redis_store # { ... optional configuration ... }

Comment: https://www.rubyguides.com/2019/04/ruby-redis/ - Using this link I have solved above problem.Thank you,